# Is there a way to join a calendar table to start and end dates of another query?

Tags: sql-server, join

I have one table with Date Keys and another Calendar table.  I want to join the two such that all of the dates between the start and end get the data.  Is that possible?

See the tables below for clarification:

Activity Table

```
Well    Activity    DateKey
A       Drill       20190101
A       Drill       20190102
A       Drill       20190106
A       Drill       20190107
A       Drill       20190108
B       Complete    20190107
B       Complete    20190108
B       Complete    20190111
B       Complete    20190115
```

Calendar Table

```
Date Key    CalendarDate
20190101    1/1/2019
20190102    1/2/2019
20190103    1/3/2019
...
```

Result Table

```
Calendar Date   Well    Activity
1/1/2019        A       Drill
1/2/2019        A       Drill
1/3/2019        A       Drill
1/4/2019        A       Drill
1/5/2019        A       Drill
1/6/2019        A       Drill
1/7/2019        A       Drill
1/7/2019        B       Complete
1/8/2019        A       Drill
1/8/2019        B       Complete
1/9/2019        B       Complete
1/10/2019       B       Complete
1/11/2019       B       Complete
1/12/2019       B       Complete
1/13/2019       B       Complete
1/14/2019       B       Complete
1/15/2019       B       Complete
1/16/2019       Null    Null
1/17/2019       Null    Null
1/18/2019       Null    Null
1/19/2019       Null    Null
```

I've tried a few different joins but nothing fills in the gaps.

```
SELECT 
    JA.[WellId]
    ,Well.[WellName]
    ,JA.[JobKey]
    ,Job.[JobType]
--  ,MIN(JA.DateKey)
--  ,MAX(JA.DateKey)
    ,Calendar.DisplayDate

FROM [WELLEZ].[PLY_WELLEZ_PRD].[rpt].[JobActivity] JA

Left Outer Join [WELLEZ].[PLY_WELLEZ_PRD].[rpt].[Well] Well on JA.[WellId] = Well.[WellId]
Left Outer Join [WELLEZ].[PLY_WELLEZ_PRD].[rpt].[Job] Job on JA.[JobId] = Job.[JobId]
Left Outer Join [PRODUCTION].[PLY_FV_PRD].[mdm].[Calendar] Calendar on Calendar.CalendarKey = JA.DateKey 

WHERE
    (well.[IsCurrentRecord] = 1 or well.[IsCurrentRecord] is null)
    and (well.[WellHasBeenDeleted] = 0 or Well.WellHasBeenDeleted is null)
    and (Job.[IsCurrentRecord] = 1 OR Job.[IsCurrentRecord] is Null)
    and JA.WellID = 104935.00

Group by 
    Calendar.DisplayDate
    ,Well.[WellName]
    ,Job.[JobType]
    ,JA.[WellId]
    ,JA.[JobKey]


Order by
    Well.[WellName]
    ,MIN(Calendar.CalendarDay)
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but we don't have enough information that may fit your case which you may not be showing us. Please answer these questions: Your result table doesn't seem to correspond to your data. Why do you want to stop on 1/19/2019? Also, can different activity mix (be different) between the same well on different dates? It seems like you need to create groups for consecutive well & activity columns and extract min and max dates and then outer join that to calendar table to produce the result.

Comment: Let's take an example. You have 5 rows for <A, Drill>. Is the idea that you want to see <A, Drill> for all dates between the minimum (Jan 1 2019) and the maximum (Jan 8 2019). If so, the first step is to find the min and max for each group, correct?

Comment: Switch your query around. The Calendar table should be the main table as it contains all of the rows you want returned. Then left join to everything else. I suppose you could do a right join but those are more confusing as it isn't as intuitive what happens.

Comment: I found that starting with the calendar made it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find the start and end date key first, then use a left join from your calendar table in order to have all dates.

```
WITH Activity  AS 
(
    SELECT 'A' AS Well,   'Drill'     AS Activity,  20190101 AS DateKey UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS Well,   'Drill'     AS Activity,  20190102 AS DateKey UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS Well,   'Drill'     AS Activity,  20190106 AS DateKey UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS Well,   'Drill'     AS Activity,  20190107 AS DateKey UNION
    SELECT 'A' AS Well,   'Drill'     AS Activity,  20190108 AS DateKey UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS Well,   'Complete'  AS Activity,  20190107 AS DateKey UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS Well,   'Complete'  AS Activity,  20190108 AS DateKey UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS Well,   'Complete'  AS Activity,  20190111 AS DateKey UNION
    SELECT 'B' AS Well,   'Complete'  AS Activity,  20190115 AS DateKey 
) , 
Calendar AS (
    SELECT  20190101 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/1/2019 ' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190102 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/2/2019 ' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190103 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/3/2019 ' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190104 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/4/2019 ' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190105 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/5/2019 ' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190106 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/6/2019 ' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190107 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/7/2019 ' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190107 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/7/2019 ' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190108 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/8/2019 ' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190108 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/8/2019 ' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190109 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/9/2019 ' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190110 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/10/2019' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190111 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/11/2019' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190112 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/12/2019' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190113 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/13/2019' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190114 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/14/2019' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190115 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/15/2019' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190116 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/16/2019' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190117 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/17/2019' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190118 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/18/2019' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate UNION
    SELECT  20190119 AS [DateKey], CAST('1/19/2019' AS DATE)  AS CalendarDate 
) 
, CTE_START_END_ACTIVITY AS (
    SELECT
            Well
           ,Activity
           ,MIN(DateKey) AS start_Datekey
           ,MAX(DateKey) AS end_Datekey
        FROM Activity
        GROUP BY
            Well
           ,Activity
)
SELECT
        d.CalendarDate
        ,a.Well
        ,a.Activity
    FROM Calendar d 
    LEFT JOIN CTE_START_END_ACTIVITY a
        ON d.DateKey BETWEEN a.start_Datekey AND end_Datekey
    ORDER BY
        D.CalendarDate
        ,a.Well
        ,a.Activity
```